# Triggering audio on Android from Particle Photon

Tags: android, audio, particles, photon

I recently completed the Hackster.io project for the Particle Internet Button which allows you to play a song on your Android triggered from the Photon. Nice project.

https://www.jeremydeprisco.com/particle-photon-starter-projects/

This worked at first, but then I upgraded to an Android Moto Z Play, and now the command to play audio doesn't work. I'd really prefer to play a sound of my choosing, uploaded and stored to my Android. So far, all I can get to happen is Google Play loads, but it asks me to subscribe. But I don't want to subscribe to Google Play. The audio that I want to play is original, created in my studio. It won't be in the Goggle Play service.

I've tried altering the location path to the file, and I've also tried other third party audio players. Seems like a simple task. So far I haven't seen anything online that addresses this. Thoughts appreciated.

Here are some paths that I tried:

file:///storage/sdcard0/120217_SpaceStation.mp3

file:///storage/emulated/0/120217_SpaceStation.mp3

/Internal Storage/Download/120217_SpaceStation.mp3

None of these worked when entered on the IFTTT side for the "Play a song" button.

Answer (score 0):

So I came back and did some testing and found that I was making this more difficult than needed.

SOLUTION: Only need the song name: 120217_SpaceStation

I still think it would be cool to programmatically assign the exact location, but it appears that both Google Play and Pulsar audio apps just do a text search for the title (without file extension).